# Matplotlib draw rectangle over image, rectangle specified in image coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I’m plotting an image like this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im, cmap = "gray")
```

I would like to draw a rectangle on top of the image with the following parameters (in image coordinates)

(0, 0, 240, 210)

(Top, left, width, height)

The docs for a rectangle patch says that the first parameter is a tuple specifying the “bottom left” of the rectangle.

```
rect = mpatches.Rectangle((0, 0 + 210), 240, 210, fill = False, linewidth = 2, edgecolor = randHex())
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

After plotting this, the rectangle shows up in the wrong place and I’m not sure why. I think there’s some kind of coordinate system mismatch between image coordinates which I’m using at the matplotlib’s coordinate system.

EDIT: If I just use `(0, 0)` it works fine, but that’s inconsistent with the docs.

Comment: @DjaballahDJEDID do you mind saying why? That would be the top right of the rectangle if I’m not mistaken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the axis goes from top to bottom, the bottom of the rectangle is actually the top, seen in data coordinates. However, what is always true is that a rectangle

```
plt.Rectangle((x, y), w, h)
```

expands from `(x,y)` to `(x+w, y+h)`.

So when we plot the same rectangle `plt.Rectangle((1,2), 2, 1)` in axes with different orientations of the respective x and y axes, it will look different.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_rect(ax):
    rect = plt.Rectangle((1,2), 2, 1)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.scatter([1], [2], s=36, color="k", zorder=3)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)

xlims = ((-4,4), (-4,4), (4,-4), (4,-4))
ylims = ((-4,4), (4,-4), (-4,4), (4,-4))

for ax, xlim, ylim in zip(axs.flat, xlims, ylims):
    plot_rect(ax)
    ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you read the wrong doc! Haha
Well, the coordinates start from the top left corner of the rectangle.

```
(x, y, w, h)
```

(x, y) are the top left corners, where (w, y) are the width and height of the rectangle.

Hope it helps.
Peace out.

Comment: Mm thanks that certainly makes more sense but take a look at this https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html

Comment: Well, there must be some mistake in the documentation. Those are top left coordinated only. Though I don't understand how the docs can be wrong. Well, we coder care for what works for us haha. So, don't worry about the docs much. If you wanna verify, check this out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53ucZ6_7_t4 And if my solution worked for ya, please check the green tick! That would be great.